# Create a multi filter button

Tags: angular

I want to create a first input for Filter By which will be a dropdown menu.
There are three options for filtering the data By Status, By Employee Id and By project Id .
If I select the first then it should open the search box for By status which will again have dropdown. And following for others two. How I can do this using Angular. If there is a link for the material then also it will be helpful as I am getting errors in my code.

Comment: Hi, What is the error you are getting? Can you add a code snippet of what have you tried please? That would help us to give you an advice or the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
   => Solution using firebase :-
    
**

 - COmponent.html

**

<mat-select formControlName="region" (ngModelChange)="onChangeFilters($event)">
              <mat-option value="" disabled>Select Region</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="1">20</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="2">22</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="3">23</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="4">24</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="5">25</mat-option>
            </mat-select>


 - **tsFile**
onChangeFilters(e){
this.data = e
}

    this.firestore
            .collection('users', (collectionRef: CollectionReference) =>
              collectionRef
                .where('email', '==', this.data)
            )
            .get()
            .subscribe((res) => {
  console.log(res)                
})
```